# Apache only transferring partial content from a Samba share

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, samba

I have an Apache server running on CentOS 5.3. It currently hosts 12 sites with no known issues. (I say this to point out that up to this point my Apache installation has performed flawlessly) I'm adding a new site where the DocumentRoot of the new VirtualHost is a Samba share.

When at the command line of the server I can `cp video.m4v ~` and the whole file is copied properly to my home directory. But when I try to access the file from IE/Firefox/Safari/Chrome it only passes back a partial result of 33k. The same thing is happening with my image and audio files. If I make the files local to the server by copying them from the share and then serving them up then the files transfer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried these? http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/RedHat/2009-04/msg00059.html

Answer (score 4):

Inside the your Apache configuration set the following Directive:

`<Directory /path/to/directory>`

`EnableSendFile Off`

`</Directory>`

That worked for me!

Comment: +1 - Worked for me as well, and fits with the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile